# Why is the first output for the deposit shown in scientific notation?

Tags: c++, decimal

```
void readAccountInfo()
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("Accounts.dat");
    string tempID;
    string tempFirst;
    string tempLast;
    string tempDeposit;
    string tempRate;
    string tempYear;
    int i = 0;
    while (fin >> tempID >> tempFirst >> tempLast >> tempDeposit >> tempRate
            >> tempYear)
    {
        accounts[i] =
        {   tempID, tempFirst, tempLast, stof(tempDeposit), stof(tempRate), stoi(tempYear)};
        i++;
    }
}

void writeAccountInfo()
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("test.dat");
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 30 && accounts[i].yearTerm != 0)
    {
        fout << accounts[i].ID << "      " << accounts[i].firstName << "      "
                << accounts[i].lastName << "                    ";
        fout.precision(2);
        fout << accounts[i].deposit << fixed;
        fout.precision(1);
        fout << "             " << accounts[i].rate << fixed;
        fout.precision(0);
        fout << "         " << accounts[i].yearTerm << endl << fixed;
        i++;
    }
}
```

The output dat file is supposed to have the deposit have two decimals but the first line always ends up in scientific notation. example 1000.00 is supposed to come out like that but instead comes out as 1 e+3.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a specific format for the output, you have to add the specifiers *before* the value. For example:

```
 fout << fixed << accounts[i].deposit;
```

What you add after a value only affects the next output.